# Multiple social login options on iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, google-plus, facebook-ios-sdk

I am creating an app with multiple login options. 
There will be a possibility to login via Facebook, Google+, and a manual login.

Its all good for now. But lets talk about the case where a user decided to logout from one account, and login using the other account. For instance, logging in via Facebook, logging out, then logging in via Google+.

This scenario causes the database to create multiple users in the database for only one user.
The only way I can think of solving this, is to find a link between all the different logins.
Options:

- Email - The user can use different emails for the different apps, or might not have his email public through one of the social apis.
- Phone Identifier - The user might let someone else use the app on his phone, or the user might have multiple devices.
- Name - There will be many people with identical names.

Due to the above not being viable options, I wanted to see how other people have approached this concern.
I am not looking to use any 3rd party frameworks.
Thanks!

Comment: `multiple users in the database for only one user` IMO it's fair to treat these as multiple users...

Comment: With that reasoning though, users might "add as friends" themselves, or get themselves as suggestions. Moreover, all their history and data collected by using the app will reset.

Comment: Yeah, I do agree that leaving them as multiple users could introduce issues, but (for example) think of any system that creates accounts based on email addresses; many people have multiple email addresses, and signing up with more than one address will create multiple accounts, as expected.

Comment: That said, if you really want to link accounts, the best way to do is by forcing the user to perform the linking themselves; say they're logged in via G+, then give them the option within the app (while still logged in) to link to Facebook; this will be the best way to ensure the linking is done correctly/securely.

Comment: That is a fair suggestion. I will look into that. Though it might cause the app to be less seamless, if the user is forced to answer another question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: No problem. In fact, I think this is how StackOverflow does it. [Check this link out](http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?noauto=true&returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent) (or go to your profile and click the 'my logins' link).